# Make 'cabbrev' work from command-line but not search prompt?

Tags: neovim, search, command-line, abbreviations

I am using NeoVim, and I automatically define an abbreviation for the string `W` every time the commandline mode starts.

However, it seems that commandline mode includes the search modes as well.

I do not want the abbreviation to exist in the search modes, so I want to delete it if it exists.

I tried `maparg('W','c',v:true)` and `mapcheck('W','c',v:true)` to check if `W` is defined as an abbreviation in command mode, but they do not seem to work.
(here `'W'` is the abbreviation I want to check for, `'c'` stands for commandline mode, and `true` is for abbreviation -- I think)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

EDIT: adding my code for defining the abbreviation for `W`:

`autocmd CmdlineEnter,CmdwinEnter :,q: cnoreabbrev W w !git add %`

(this allows me to add the file to the local git repo by typing `:W<CR>`

EDIT:
Thanks to the answers below, the solution is:

```
cnoremap <expr> W (getcmdtype() == ':') ? "w !git add %" : "W"
```

Thank y'all -- it is very useful.

Comment: Can you include the definition of the `W` abbreviation? `mapcheck('W', 'c', v:true)` works for me and returns `whatever` if I define it as `cabbrev W whatever`, not sure what's the case with your particular setting...

Comment: Don't use auto-command here. It's pointless.

Comment: @Benben The best way to indicate that the posted answer solved your issue is to "accept" the answer (click on the gray check below the score, it'll turn green) rather than edit the question to include the answer there. Could you please do that instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use a mapping instead of an abbreviation then this'll do...

```
:cnoremap <expr> W (getcmdtype() == ':') ? "foobar" : "W"
```

From command-line you get `W` resolving to whatever you specify where I have "foobar". OTOH, if you enter `W` during a search then `getcmdtype()` returns `/` or `?` and the ternary expression evaluates to false and inserts "W".

And, per @filbranden, the same thing works with `cabbrev`...

```
:cabbrev <expr> W (getcmdtype() == ':') ? "foobar" : "W"
```

You may know this already but, FYI, there's a difference between these: the `cmap` version will insert the mapped string immediately after you enter the `W` while `cabbrev` requires entering an additional, non-keyword character immediately afterward (per normal abbreviation mechanics).

Comment: Using `<expr>` also works with a `cabbrev`...

Comment: @filbranden Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Wow -- Thanks guys!
What does `<expr>` do?

Comment: Treats the right-hand side as a Vim expression to be evaluated rather than a literal string.

Comment: Thanks all! This answer made it unnecessary to remove the definition everytime I enter search mode.

Comment: @Benben I notice you didn't accept the answer. If that's just an oversight I'd appreciate it if you could give me that green check mark. Cheers.